# AAD B2C - Is a user authorized to change their own custom attributes?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to use custom attributes in AAD B2C as a shortcut for authorization. I would love to set values on users that I can use in my apis to know what they have access to do.

I see that I can create a User flow for a user to edit their own attributes, but that is the opposite of what I want.

If I don't create a user flow to edit the attribute, can I be confident that the user can't edit it on their own through Microsoft Graph or something like that? I tried doing it through graph but I can't tell if I did something wrong or if the user is not allowed to change it.

Comment: I've been kinda looking about the same, something so simple but made so hard. 
Even with the permission "User.ReadWrite" provided, it still doesn't allow to do PATCH to neither https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}.

I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to depend on User attributes for authorization. As user profile information (user attributes)can be [managed by the use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)r self or organization level.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I read that documentation, but it doesn't specifically talk about the custom attribute feature of AAD B2C. 

This documentation gives an example of setting a loyaltyId custom attribute

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes.

LoyaltyId sounds like something I wouldn't want the user to be able to change, but I didn't see anything in the documentation confirming that concern of mine.

I may open a ticket with azure support about that specific piece of documentation just to be sure.

Comment: If no one else chimes in soon I'll mark your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think users can adjust their own attributes if they don't have the graph permissions in Azure. When signing in your users within your application you can allow them to access certain scopes. As long as they cant access these scopes they cannot perform any actions on the graph API. Updating user details would in this case require 'User.ReadWrite' scope assigned.